# shell how to repeat line in a text with the value of the end of the line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need the following text to be repeated with the number at the end of the line with bash:

```
test1, red, 1
test2, green, 2
test3, white, 3
```

this need to give the following result

```
test1, red
test2, green
test2, green
test3, white
test3, white
test3, white
```

Please explain the steps if needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wtih awk you could do something like this:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "}{for(i=1;i<=$NF;i++)print $1,$2}' file
test1, red
test2, green
test2, green
test3, white
test3, white
test3, white
```

Comment: you may want to change `$3` to `$NF` to make answer perfect.

Comment: Thanks , can you please explain me your answer, I am not yet a awk guru. what I see is that you use the BEGIN{FS=OFS=", "} to set the separator for input and output but it's not clear to me how the third column is read from the last part of the command {for(i=1;i<=$NF;i++)print $1,$2}.  if i have 8 column with number in the middle will the command be the same?

Comment: @joe: `NF` is the number of fields, so `$NF` is the value of the last field in the line. You could replace the loop with `for(i=1;i<=$3;i++) print $1,$2` if you find it more readable. If you had 8 columns and the number of times printed is say in the fourth field, you would write `for(i=1;i<=$4;i++) print $1,$2,$3,$5,$6,$7,$8`

Comment: Thanks user000001for your explanations

Answer (score 2):

```
while IFS=,  read -r p1 p2 p3;
do 
  for((i=1;i<=$p3;i++));
     do 
       echo $p1,$p2;
     done ;
done<inputfile
```

Output:

```
test1, red
test2, green
test2, green
test3, white
test3, white
test3, white
```

Explanation:

This will break each line separated by comma sign. Once it is done check for the third column and reiterate it as per the value of  3rd column.

*Downside: This is not flexible enough if number of columns are changed.*  You many want to use `awk` and its last column value `$NF` to iterate over loop.

Comment: Thanks I will go for the awk answer